# Error with clipboard data when copying all using Ctrl+A in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am working with clipboard data processing for a new project. I am facing a strange problem in IE 10 (Version 10.0.9200.16660)

Following is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>page - title</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).on('copy', function(e){ 
            var body_element, selection, pageLink, copytext, newdiv, url;
            url = document.location.href;
            body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            selection = window.getSelection();
            alert(selection);
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <ol>
            <li>Hi</li>    
            <li>Hi</li>   
            <li>Hi</li>  
            <li>Hi</li>   
            <li>Hi</li>    
        </ol>    
        </body>
        </html>
```

**Error**

1. Save the above code to an HTML file
2. Run it
3. Use Ctrl + A, Ctrl + C
4. It is alerting the whole html, including the page title, the javascripts etc.. in IE (see the attached[image] image) but working fine in Chrome.

Can someone give me some hint on whats happening?

Comment: give [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard) a try, it makes copy for the clipboard really easy and no worries with crosss browser problems

Comment: It is NOT alerting the whole HTML. However, the selection does include the plain text content in the header - the content of the `<title>` and the `<script>` elements. Why it does that, no idea. But if you select the page by dragging with the mouse, it does select only the the content of the body.